# How do I make a read-only "Connect to ODBC" connection in SAS Proc SQL?

Tags: sql, sas, connection, odbc, readonly

I am creating a SAS macro function that my co-workers may use to connect via ODBC connections to various databases using SAS Proc SQL, to run pass-through SQL code. I would like the connection to be read-only, even though the users have write-access to the databases. I can do this in a LIBNAME statement, with ACCESS=READONLY:

```
LIBNAME myLib ODBC NOPROMPT="DATABASE=myDB;Server=myServer;DRIVER={SQL Server};Trusted_Connection=Yes;" ACCESS=READONLY;
```

I can create a read-write connection like so:

```
PROC SQL ;
  CONNECT TO ODBC AS myCon(NOPROMPT="DATABASE=myDB;Server=myServer;DRIVER={SQL Server};Trusted_Connection=Yes;")  ;
  EXECUTE( INSERT INTO myTable(myColumn) VALUES(1) ) BY myCon ; ** insert a row where myColumn=1;
QUIT;
```

But inserting ACCESS=READONLY as an option in Connect To ODBC (), like `CONNECT TO ODBC AS myCon(ACCESS=READONLY NOPROMPT="DATABASE=myDB;Server=myServer;DRIVER={SQL Server};Trusted_Connection=Yes;")  ;`, results in <kbd>ERROR: Invalid option name ACCESS.</kbd>

I know that there is nothing I can put within the connection string to make the connection read-only. Is there some way to make this `Connect to ODBC ...` into a read-only connection?

Answer (score 0):

First, you can do it using the libname!

```
proc sql;
  connect using mylib;
  ... sql stuff ...
quit;
```

Second, this is going to be in the ODBC init string (so inside the "quotes") and will depend on what driver you're using.  The modern SQL server drivers have `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly`; see for example [this doc page for the v15 driver](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/native-client/applications/using-connection-string-keywords-with-sql-server-native-client?view=sql-server-ver15).  I don't know if the older `{SQL Server}` driver  supports that or not.

Comment: I tried making a "read-only" libname with `LIBNAME mylib ODBC NOPROMPT="(odbc connection string)" ACCESS=READONLY ;` but was still able to write to the database. I'm guessing that there is no SAS-level way to control read-write privileges in an ODBC connection.
The `ApplicationIntent=ReadOnly;` approach did not work in my `{SQL Server}` driver. Maybe I can get our IT to update the server drivers.

Comment: Hmm, that may be a bug (or at least, an issue they didn't think of) - the `connect using` is relatively new, so it might be worth raising a track with SAS.  At minimum, you should get a warning or note in the log saying that the connection can't be made read only!

Comment: An example of passthrough code that will write to the "ACCESS=READONLY" library connection is:
`LIBNAME mylib ODBC NOPROMPT="(odbc connection string)" ACCESS=READONLY;
PROC SQL;
CONNECT WITH mylib AS mycon;
EXECUTE(CREATE TABLE sometable (some_count INT)) BY mycon;
QUIT;`